# Gems groups in the Gemfile for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is it necessary to divide the gems inside the Gemfile in groups, i.e. production, test, development, even though I want to use the exact gems for all of the environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the exact gems for all of the environments, you don't need to specify it in group.

You can find more about bundler groups here :

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/

http://bundler.io/v1.3/groups.html